# Multiple collection modifications

Tags: mongodb, collections, model, endpoint

I'm building an endpoint that will change the "deleted" property on a post in the POSTS collection to true (which works fine) AND then also find all comments in the COMMENTS collection that are in response to that post (which I did in a different route) and change all of their parentDeleted properties to true as well (this is where I am having trouble).

Here is the route for deleting a post:

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Post.findById(req.params.id).then(post => {
  post.deleted = true

  post.save().then(post => res.json(post))
  })  
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ categories: 'No post found'}))
})
```

And here is the route for finding all comments in response to the post:

```
router.get('/:id/comments', (req, res) => {
  Comment.find({ parentId: req.params.id})
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ categories: 'No post found'}))
})
```

I've tried adding the comments logic to the post logic and mapping through the comments:

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Post.findById(req.params.id).then(post => {
    post.deleted = true

    post.save()
  }).then(post => {
    Comment.find({ parentId: req.params.id})
      .then(comments => {
        comments.map((comment) => {
          return comment.parentDeleted = true
       })
    })
  })
  .then(post => res.json(post))   
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ categories: 'No post found'}))
})
```

The post's deleted status is changed to true, but the parentDeleted status of the comments remain false. Any suggestions? This is my first question posted so any feedback on etiquette would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, @dcortes!

It appears from the code you have posted that you are not saving the comments after you have changed their parentDeleted value to true.

So, for the relevant portion of the code, something akin to this might work better:

```
Comment.find({ parentId: req.params.id})
  .then(comments => {
    comments.map((comment) => {

      // Set the appropriate value.
      comment.parentDeleted = true;

      // Then save it. 
      // You can modify what is returned, if needed. 
      return comment.save();
   })
})
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the comments once they're saved, so I've just returned the result of comment.save().

Note that if your broader question is, "Is it possible to modify multiple collections using one endpoint?" the answer is definitely yes.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it!